# Execution failed for task ':expo-permissions:compileDebugKotlin'

Tags: android, react-native, expo, expo-camera, expo-permissions

I am working on a React Native app where I included some expo libraries (bare workflow). I had successfully used `expo-location`, but now after I installed also `expo-camera`, the app won't build anymore with `npm run android`, did not try yet on ios.

It will crash at `:expo-permissions:compileDebugKotlin` step.

I did find the problem on another forum, they were saying to update the `buildToolsVersion` from `build.gradle` to `29.0.2` but it already was on `29.0.2`. Then I updated `react-native-unimodules` which is required to use expo libraries and contains expo-permissions. It didn't work. Right now, my current versions of libs are:

```
"react-native-unimodules": "^0.12.0"

"expo-permissions": "~10.0.0"

"expo-camera": "^9.1.1"
```

Do you have any ideas? Did someone met this problem also?

Thanks

A more elaborate stacktrace is this:

```
Task :expo-permissions:compileDebugKotlin FAILED

Deprecated Gradle features were used in this build, making it incompatible with Gradle 7.0.
Use '--warning-mode all' to show the individual deprecation warnings.
See https://docs.gradle.org/6.2/userguide/command_line_interface.html#sec:command_line_warnings
153 actionable tasks: 4 executed, 149 up-to-date
e: app\node_modules\expo-permissions\android\src\main\java\expo\modules\permissions\PermissionsService.kt: (16, 40): Unresolved reference: PermissionAwareActivity
e: app\node_modules\expo-permissions\android\src\main\java\expo\modules\permissions\PermissionsService.kt: (170, 17): Unresolved reference: PermissionAwareActivity
e: app\node_modules\expo-permissions\android\src\main\java\expo\modules\permissions\PermissionsService.kt: (236, 19): Unresolved reference: PermissionAwareActivity
e: app\node_modules\expo-permissions\android\src\main\java\expo\modules\permissions\PermissionsService.kt: (237, 62): Too many arguments for public final fun requestPermissions(@NonNull p
0: Array<(out) String!>, p1: Int): Unit defined in android.app.Activity
e: app\node_modules\expo-permissions\android\src\main\java\expo\modules\permissions\PermissionsService.kt: (237, 64): Cannot infer a type for this parameter. Please specify it explicitly.
e: app\node_modules\expo-permissions\android\src\main\java\expo\modules\permissions\PermissionsService.kt: (237, 77): Cannot infer a type for this parameter. Please specify it explicitly.
e: app\node_modules\expo-permissions\android\src\main\java\expo\modules\permissions\PermissionsService.kt: (237, 97): Cannot infer a type for this parameter. Please specify it explicitly.

FAILURE: Build failed with an exception.
```

Answer (score 5):

You may not want to take the version being referenced by others online, but, instead take the version of what you have installed locally, which would vary depending on when you last updated your Android SDK.

On Windows you can look up your SDK version (tools version):

```
dir %ANDROID_SDK_ROOT%\build-tools
```

Probably *nix systems will have a similar SDK path (did not check):

```bash
ls -al $ANDROID_SDK_ROOT\build-tools
```

Comment: I just used another lib because I didn't have enough time to continue investigating this, but thank you for your answer, maybe it will help somebody (y)

Comment: I am beginner to react native , saw version 30 everywhere for react native vision camera inside node_modules folder, changed in my android/build.gradle and viola, it ran perfectly

Comment: I am getting the same error and i cannot solve it ,my build script is below? Could the problem be here?
buildscript {
    ext {
        buildToolsVersion = "29.0.2"
        minSdkVersion = 21
        compileSdkVersion = 29
        targetSdkVersion = 29
    }

Answer (score 2):

You might have installed a newer version of `expo-camera`.
I've had the same issue with the `expo-clipboard` package.

My project was using `expo@44` and I followed the official docs and ran `npm install expo-clipboard` which installed the latest version, which is **compatible with the latest expo version** at this time is `expo@46`.

The simple fix is to use the right version based on your expo version.

1. Find your expo version in your package.json. Mine was `"expo": "~44.0.0",`
2. Go to `https://github.com/expo/expo/tree/sdk-{version}/packages`. (Mine was
   https://github.com/expo/expo/tree/sdk-44/packages).
3. Find the package you want to use like `expo-clipboard` and go to its package.json file to check the version Ex. https://github.com/expo/expo/blob/sdk-44/packages/expo-clipboard/package.json#L3
4. Install that specific version `npm install expo-clipboard@2.1.1`

Hope it helps!

Comment: It didn't work dude!

Answer (score 1):

I have solved this issue by downgrading react-native-unimodules from version 0.13.2 to 0.12.0

Answer (score 0):

I solved this by downgrading react-native-unimodules from version 0.13.2 to 0.12.0,
I think the problem is that the new version of unimodules requires upgrading your
android build tools so the **right thing is not downgrading the unimodules but upgrading your build tools from 28.0.0 to 29.0.3 like this:**

```
buildscript {
    ext {
        buildToolsVersion = "29.0.3"
        minSdkVersion = 21
        compileSdkVersion = 29
        targetSdkVersion = 29
```

Comment: Question: you mean downgrading the react-native-unimodules. Is this correct? Replacing this
` "react-native-unimodules": "^0.13.3",`
with this?
`"react-native-unimodules": "0.12.0",`

Comment: A: Removed the package with v 1.13.2 and installed the older version 1.12.0

Comment: There is no react-native-unimodules v 1.13.2. In fact, three is no version 1. We are still at version zero. What package are you talking about? https://www.npmjs.com/package/react-native-unimodules. Please be specific with the package name or family name.

Comment: 0.12.0 my bad , Edited the answer

Answer (score 0):

I got mine working by reducing my expo version from 43.0.0 to 40.0.0 and setting 'sdkVersion': "38.0.0". It appears the versions didn't match with each other or with some other expo dependencies.

in **app.json:**

```
{
  "name": "MyApp",
  "displayName": "MyApp",
      "expo": {
        "name": "MyApp",
        "slug": "myapp.app",
        "sdkVersion": "38.0.0"
      }
}
```

...and in **package.json**:

```
"dependencies" {
    "expo": "^40.0.0",
    "expo-file-system": "^9.3.0",
    "expo-linking": "~2.0.1",
    "expo-splash-screen": "~0.8.0",
    "expo-status-bar": "~1.0.3",
    "expo-updates": "^0.4.2",
}
```

Answer (score 0):

I'm facing the same issue when I rebuild my project or try to run on a Device.

I install expo-permissions by using `expo install expo-permissions` on my expo project and then go to Android Studio and Sync my project after that I clean my project which you can find on **build/Clean Project** after this I install Kotlin extension on Android Studio after that again clean project and then **rebuild Project** (build/Rebuild Project).

These Steps resolve my issue.