# expo-document-picker:compileDebugKotlin FAILED

Tags: android, react-native, expo

Following is my configuration,

```
buildToolsVersion = "30.0.3"
minSdkVersion = 21
compileSdkVersion = 30
targetSdkVersion = 30
googlePlayServicesAuthVersion = "16.0.1"
firebaseMessagingVersion = "21.1.0"
```

This is package.json details,

```
"react": "16.13.1",
"react-native": "0.63.2",
"react-native-unimodules": "0.13.3"
```

I tired this SO [answser1](https://stackoverflow.com/a/67614549/8364900) and [answser2](https://stackoverflow.com/a/66968348/8364900). But I didn't solve my issue.

Can Some one help me to get rid of this issue?

Comment: Issue got resolved after migrating from `react-native-unimodules` to `expo modules`.

Comment: Cool thanks for the update. I've been having similar issue. Will migrate to expo mudules.

Comment: @NgimaSherpa Glad, This update helped you